# Is there a way to get historic traffic flow data from the traffic api?

Tags: here-api, traffic

I have been using traffic api to get real-time traffic speeds, but I was wondering if there is a way to request traffic speed for a specific day, specific time.

Comment: Welcome to SO, I hope you find the answer to your question soon!